# Handling Network connecton issues in amazon simpledb

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

As part of my android application, I are planning to use simpledb NoSQL service offered by Amazon.

I was able to use the APIs of the simpledb without any issue. However I have issues in case when there is network connection problem.
For ex: If I add an item or attribute to simpledb when there is network connection [i.e., the mobile is online], the replication is successful. However if I do the same in case of no network connection [i.e., the mobile is offline] and then add an additional item with network connection [i.e., the mobile is back to online], only the new item is replicated.
Basically this means that I would need to do the book-keeping of making a local store of the item (or attributes) in case when there is no network connection and, then pull these from local store and replicate when the network connection is back.

Is there something that I am missing here, or is it like the developer has to take care of the book-keeping to handle the network issue.

I saw that cognito is supposed to help here, but I see that it is just a key-value pair local-store. In which case I again have to pull the key-value pair from the local-store and then convert it to key-attribute pair and send it to my simpledb.

Please let me know how I can handle this case. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK has a conceptual notion of high level and low level clients. The low level clients just do request/response to the server. If the device is offline the request is fail and that is all that happens. The SimpleDB client you are using is a low level client because SimpleDB does not have a high level client.

There are currently 4 high level clients that handle saving data if the device is offline. Mobile Analytics, S3 Transfer Utility, Kinesis Recorder, Cognito Sync Manager. In your case it sounds like only S3 Transfer Utility (blob data storage you could serialize something) or Cognito Sync (key/value) could be useful, and that entirely depends on how the data is structured. I wouldn't recommend using either of these as strictly offline storage to then put back into SimpleDB. I would either use S3/Cognito for storing/retrieving the data entirely or stick to SimpleDB (or Dynamo) and store the data locally if you detect the device is offline.

It wouldn't be too hard to catch network exceptions coming from the SimpleDB client and then store the request in a local SQLite database, and when you detect the network has come back (or is available upon app start) you can send the requests you stored.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks WestonE for the reply, really appreciate the same.